# Admin ui form category tree population issue

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform

I've got an admin ui form with category tree field

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Announce/blob/429e2f6228b5911f261df6f6855d76913c934f9a/view/adminhtml/ui_component/xigen_announce_group_form.xml#L159-L189

```xml
        <field name="category" component="Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category" sortOrder="60" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <required>false</required>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                </validation>
                <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
                <label translate="true">Category</label>
                <dataScope>category</dataScope>
                <componentType>field</componentType>
                <listens>
                    <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
                </listens>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

I've got the field populating and data is saving correctly

The remaining issue is that the field appears blank on load

[image]

But sorts itself out when you click

[image]

I've missed a step. Any ideas?

Comment: The ui_component code seems correct, you should be check in `Xigen\Announce\Model\Group\DataProvider`  file. Please check on this file on `getData()` method which is render or not your categories data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment on question pointed me in right direction. Worth highlighted that this is because I'm using a multiselect. Single i.e. `<item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>` no issue.

XML and db data is correct

Had to update `Xigen\Announce\Model\Group\DataProvider::getData()`

My form is tabbed. So additional layer here. But went from this...

```php
    /**
     * Get data
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()][Data::GROUP_TAB] = $model->getData();
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('xigen_announce_group');

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()][Data::GROUP_TAB] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('xigen_announce_group');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
```

To this...

```php
    /**
     * Get data
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $form = $this->loadedData[$model->getId()][Data::GROUP_TAB] = $model->getData();
            $form['category'] = explode(',', $form['category']);
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('xigen_announce_group');

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()][Data::GROUP_TAB] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('xigen_announce_group');
        } else {
            if ($items) {
                if ($model->getData('category')) {
                    $group[$model->getId()][Data::GROUP_TAB] = $form;
                    return $group;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
```

This answer helped https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/270807/70343