# Switch out category drop down for Ajax seach due to high category number

Tags: magento2.4.6

I'm fairly new to Magento and have tried some other threads on here with little success so far.

We've got almost 29k categories and brings this module to halt every time we have use this module, especially if there's multiple uses.

```
  <field name="source_category_data_new">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Owner\Import\Ui\Component\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Destination</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <!-- <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>-->
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">source_category_data_new</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Owner_Import/js/form/element/selectize</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Owner_Import/form/element/selectize</item>
                    </item>
```

This is the code I'm try to substitute for  the same select box that appears on the Add Product page. An Ajax call that doesn't stop the server every time the page loads.

[Drop Down Multi-select category Ui Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270657/drop-down-multi-select-category-ui-component)

This link gives the code however I can't seem to get it to work.

```
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_id</item>
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

```
I'm getting a js

jQuery.Deferred exception: this.parentName.split('.').last is not a function. (In 'this.parentName.split('.').last()', 'this.parentName.split('.').last' is undefined) 
configureDataScope — select.js:39
initConfig — general.js:28
(anonymous function) — wrapper.js:109
initConfig — select.js:28
(anonymous function) — wrapper.js:109
initialize — class.js:70
initialize — element.js:103
(anonymous function) — wrapper.js:109
initialize — abstract.js:76
(anonymous function) — wrapper.js:109
initialize — select.js:123
(anonymous function) — wrapper.js:109
UiClass — class.js:49
initComponent — layout.js:137
fire — jquery.js:3500
fireWith — jquery.js:3630
mightThrow — jquery.js:3825
(anonymous function) — jquery.js:3834
(anonymous function) — jquery.js:3864
mightThrow — jquery.js:3766
(anonymous function) — jquery.js:3834
```

And also

```
[Warning] Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom (loader_old.js, line 205)
```

Anyone generous enough to lend me a few minutes to show a newbie how to fix this easily?

Greatly appreciated in advance.

Magento 2.4.6, php 8.2